# Restarting network on Debian 5/6

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

I need to change static defined IP addresses on 2 Debian servers. 1 server is running on Debian 5 and another one is running on Debian 6.

I'm connecting to them over SSH so I'm wondering what is the safest way to restart networking service and apply changes to interfaces so new IP apply successfully and I can connect back to them over new IPs?

Will `/etc/init.d/networking restart` or `service networking restart` do the right work if I run them in screen because I'm reading that networking restart command is deprecated : `Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces` and sometimes interfaces don't update to new assigned IPs?

Are there any other "more safe" ways to restart networking and apply changes to interfaces over SSH?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone having same problem the solution that worked for me is running the following command in screen:

```
service networking stop; sleep 5; service networking start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/networking stop; sleep 5; /etc/init.d/networking start
```

Using `/etc/init.d/networking restart` or `service networking restart` got me deprecated info and my network interfaces failed to start.